# Image Source Completion for Sublime Text 2

Tags: html, autocomplete, aptana, sublimetext

First of all, I'm not entirely sure if this fits into stackoverflow, or should rather be placed into programmers or superuser. If I posted into the wrong page, I'm sorry.

To the question:

In Aptana Studio, for example, there's a very nice feature for the `src`-attribute for `<img>`-tags. When typing into the src-attribute, a directory-listing is shown in the autocomplete-contextmenu, so you can directly select image files and the path is inserted into the attribute.

Here is what I mean:

[image: Aptana Img src]

Is there any way, a plugin or something alike, so I can get this behaviour into Sublime Text 2? Preferably working for HTML-Markup and CSS background-images?

**edit**:
Meanwhile I posted this on the sublime userecho, maybe something will come up trough this. I'll keep this question updated.

[Sublime Userecho](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/61330-image-source-completion/)

Comment: I'd like to have this as well. Anyone got any good starting point?

Comment: This would also be good for Coda.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck just curious, does Coda2 have it now?

Comment: @GNi33 Good question. I actually haven't updated to Coda2 yet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just created a plugin to do this.  You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/1608287

EDIT: the plugin is now available through Package Control.  Just search for "AutoFileName."

Comment: would love to try it, unfortunately I don't know how to trigger the function? do i need to set some key binding for this?

Comment: It works using the built in autocomplete.  So just press control+space.  However, it is context specific, so it will only trigger in strings (or if you use css, it will trigger in `background-image: url(PATH_TO_FILE))`

Comment: awesome! got it working over package control. Some different styling for filetypes or whatever would be nice but after all, this is doing exactly what I want. Thank you!

Comment: I installed it, but it's not working. :( Am I missing something?

Comment: @Web_Designer, It's designed to work in specific instances.  So pressing / then control+space should activate it.  Check out the README (https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName) for usage info.  If it's still not working, I would prefer if you filed a report through github.  Thanks.

Comment: You have no idea what you made! This is greatest plugin I found! ))) This feature MUST be implemented into sublime itself. It's showing the size and the names. Million thanks to you! )) you made me happy!